# Publishing .vue to npm for use with browserify

Tags: npm, vue.js, bundle, browserify, vue-component

How can a .vue file (as a parent component with child .vue files) be published to npm so that you can install, require, and use it as a component with browserify as

```
let component = require('published-vue-component');
```

I only use browserify; I don't use webpack at all. I thus bundle all `.vue` files into a single `build.js` using a vueify transform. All of the information I see currently about this either a.) reads that you should export your main .vue file (doesn't work) or b.) involves webpack.

If you go ahead and bundle the component with a vueify transform and set `"main": "the/bundle/path/index.js"`, it seems that a vueify transform can't work without a template rendering function and thus isn't intended for single components.

If you simply export the parent .vue file, when you require the component you're going to get a syntax error from the first character of the `<template>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you bundle your component as a umd module, then you can import it into browserify or webpack. Use rollup and this plugin: http://vuejs.github.io/rollup-plugin-vue/

I ran into this issue with my vue-autosuggest library, where browserify [users were experiencing issues](https://github.com/Educents/vue-autosuggest/issues/18) importing my module.

Check out this example rollup config for inspiration:
https://github.com/Educents/vue-autosuggest/blob/master/build/rollup.umd.config.js

Hope this helps!

Comment: this claims to do what i need - thanks! sparse docs for rollup-plugin-vue; it's going to take a few hours to try rollup and figure out what you've done in the config. can accept after i get it working.

Comment: thanks very much for this info. i assume this would work, but there aren't any docs for the plugin, and i'd have to schedule a weekend to learn rollup. maybe i'll get to it in the coming months; in the meantime i can neither assert nor deny that this works. thanks much for your time.